# jquery validate errorPlacement

Tags: jquery-validate

How do you set different placements for different input types? More specifically how do you add another li after the one whos child label has an error class? To be more clear I want to specify that for fieldset "#SomeID" the error elements are in a new div/li/p whatever below their parent input.

```
<fieldset id="SomeID">
stuff
<div class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" name="BP" id="BP">I have read and agree to the Billing Policy above.</div>
<div class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" name="TA" id="TA">I have read and agree to the Terms and Agreement <a class="linkTA"><span>Learn More...</span></a></div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u mean this?

```
 $("label.errorclass").append($("<li class='errmsg'>some error</li>"));
```

Comment: actually I meant using something like if(element.clsest("#fieldsetID").length ) { error.appendTo( element.next("li")); but it's not working

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Comment: I assume the error class is assigned in the toggle div. Try                         $("div.errorclass").closest("#fieldsetID").prepend($("<div class='errmsg'>some error</div>"));

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select the li with the error class and use $.after to insert some html directly after it.

```
$('li.error_class').after('<li>some stuff here</li>');
```